# Converting string to date time using Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I am not a perl programmer, but I'm trying to update someone else's code.  I need to format the date and time. I have three variables returned from a database. One variable contains the time, one has AM/PM, on has the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. For example:

```
variable1 = 10:00
variable2 = PM
variable3 = 11/27/2019
```

I need to take these three variables and format them accordingly: **2019-11-27 20:00:00**

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: I think you mean 22:00:00

Answer (score 2):

The strptime and strftime functions can do this. One version of these is provided by the core module [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $time = '10:00';
my $ampm = 'PM';
my $date = '11/27/2019';

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime("$date $time $ampm", '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p');
print $tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "\n";
```